# Wordpress - adding custom post type category to menu

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named 'The Books', and a relative category named 'The Books' for these custom posts.

When I add the category The Posts to my nav menu, it doesn't work because it goes to the URL */category/the-books* instead of just going to */the-books*. If I posted this in the default post section it shows correctly, but when I post in the custom post section it does not return my post. I can,  of course, add individual posts from my custom post section to the nav menu, but can't figure out how to add an archive page of the custom posts.

My permalinks are set to: URL/%postname%/ so I'm not sure why that is happening.

Here's the function for my custom posts:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'hpl_books',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'The Books' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Book' )
            ),
            'taxonomies' => array('category'),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'the-books'),
        )
    );
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to add a category "the-books" in order to display the results.

Have you created a view in your page-templates directory called "archive-hpl_books.php?" That's the file WordPress will look for to display the archive of your custom post type. Basically, you would create a page called "the-books" or whatever, then set archive-hpl_books.php as the template.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

I'm only responding to this because I just went through a similar issue, so I'm down to help out. :)

Comment: Ah yes, I had that, but I didn't understand how to call it using the wordpress custom menus - Sometimes the answers are so easy, I'll just make a custom link to /the-books